# SWFObject not playing MP3 in IE10 and lower with new Adobe Flash upgrade

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, flash, swfobject

I am using SWFObject 1.5 with flash player 14.0.0.145 and SW flv player 3.x.x. My code used to work fine in all version of IE, FF and chrome earlier(Until i think we had flash 14.0.0.125), but after the recent upgrade its not working in IE 10 and lower while works fine in IE 11, FF and chrome.

Any suggestion? Also any link to newer version of SW flv player would be helpful too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/swfobject.js'></script>
</head><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div id="audio_clip">You need to upgrade your Flash Player to at least version 8 to view this video content.<a id="1" href="http://www.adobe.com/flashplayer/">Download the latest version of Flash Player</a></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
var so = new SWFObject("js/flvplayer_updated.swf","flvplayer","592","342","8","#000000");
so.addVariable("file", "<s:property value="audioUrl"/>");
so.addVariable("autostart", "true");
so.addVariable("screencolor", "#FFFFFF");
so.write("audio_clip");
// ]]>
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: What's happening? Are you being prompted to upgrade your version of Flash Player?

Comment: All the browsers are already having the latest version of flash(14.0.0.145). It does not prompt anything. The player comes fine, but does not play anything. I tried downgrading the flash player and it works fine with old version.

Comment: >>Also any link to newer version of SW flv player would be helpful too ...................................................... My Response:
I could fine the v5 for sw flv player, but no luck with that too :(